# Implementing IQueryable with multiple predicates in Where()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I am currently working through creating an IQueryable Linq Provider based on this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb546158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Things are working perfectly with the ExpressionTreeModifier when the Where() has only a single condition, i.e. (x => x > 10); but, as soon as the Where() includes an 'AndAlso' (x => x > 10 && x < 20), the Queryable is no longer returning any results.  What is the proper approach to handling/parsing/flattening the multiple conditionals here?

Edit 1: 
This is not the right thing to do but appears to have initially made things function ... In the Context's Execute() method where the modified tree was passed into the IQueryable's Provider.CreateQuery() call I simply wrapped the IEnumerable.AsQueryable() in a ConstantExpression and that appears to be have made things function now.  That said, I am slightly concerned that I have lost other functionality here, but it's unclear what that lost functionality is, at this time.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you need to gather all parameters from Where expression and sent them somewhere like in sample article? In case of `IEnumerable.AsQueryable()` it will execute it just as for typical list.

Comment: If you want an answer to your question, please be specific of what you are doing, what do you want to achieve, and what have you tried. The proper approach always depends on your requirements :)

Comment: @Sergey - in the example code in the article the original expression is pushed back onto the queryable after the constant expression for the Queryable<T> has been replaced by the IEnumerble.  When this processing happens for a Where predicate that has multiple conditionals the Queryable yields no results, whereas when there is only one conditional in the Where predicate it yields results as expected.